# Computing the set of fixed points of a map

Tags: euclidean-geometry, fixed-point-theorems

Compute the set of fixed points of the following map:

$f(X) := (y,-x)$ when $X=(x,y)$

So for this, do I just have to solve the system of equation such as:

$x=y$

$-x=y$?

Plugging the first into the second gives -y=y, which only happens when y=0.

So then what would the set of fixed points be?

(1,-1)?

Comment: Yes, you only have to solve the system $x=y, -x=y$. You correctly deduced that $y=0$, but then $x=0$ too. The fixed point is then the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: Yeah, idk why I wrote (1,-1).  Once I get the y or x value, then I just plug that into the map to get the other part? And that provides the set of fixed points?

Comment: Pretty much. You just want to find all points $(x,y)$ that satisfies $f(x,y)=(x,y)$ (those are exactly the fixed points), so you get a system of equations to solve. In some cases, you can get an infinite set of solutions (say, if $f(x,y)=(x,0)$, then any point $(x,0)$ is a fixed point). In this case, the system of equations happens to have a unique solution, achieved by explicitly solving the equations.